# Mysql - Specified Key is too long, max key length is 1024 bytes despite encoding type being latin1 and index contains 2 column(512 each)

Tags: mysql

Getting the following error on update with join :
Mysql - Specified Key is too long, max key length is 1024 bytes despite encoding type being latin1 and index contains 2 varchar columns(512 each)
**Mysql version - 5.7.29**

**Details** :
There are 3 columns: **abc**, **pk1**, **pk2**
DataTypes of columns :
**abc** - json
**pk1** - varchar(512)
**pk2** - varchar(512)
There is one composite key => (**pk1**, **pk2**)
This gives me Specified Key is too long, max key length is 1024 bytes despite encoding type being **latin1**.
If I change datatype for **abc** to **varchar(512)**, I don't encounter this error.
Any idea on why this would happen, as **abc** is **not a part of the composite key**.
Please visit the fiddle link - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wB7Ee9Rz8nLS3KEKU59WPf/3 to find the issue
**Sample code to reproduce the issue:**

```
create table test (abc json default null, pk1 varchar(512) not null, pk2 varchar(512) not null, primary key (pk1, pk2), xyz int(11)) CHARACTER SET = latin1;
create table temp (abc json, pk1 varchar(512) not null, pk2 varchar(512) not null,  xyz int(11)) CHARACTER SET = latin1;

explain UPDATE `test` T1  INNER JOIN `temp` T2 ON T1.`pk1` = T2.`pk1` AND T1.`pk2` = T2.`pk2` SET T1.`abc` = T2.`abc`


  [1]: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wB7Ee9Rz8nLS3KEKU59WPf/3
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, both tables are created successfully. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0526b184904938ed1ff9b61caab2bd00). Try to edit the fiddle and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Have edited the question, for the exact use-case

Comment: Your "exact use-case" does NOT reproduce the problem which you tell about. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d7afa5f6d217d1d823a0784d1bcbdc7). Maybe you look on wrong window?

Comment: It fails, if you change the version to 5.7

Comment: The fiddle for 5.7 doesn't work on this server at all. Nevertheless - no problems on 5.7 too [fiddle on another server](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wB7Ee9Rz8nLS3KEKU59WPf/0)

Comment: This fails when you add the update query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wB7Ee9Rz8nLS3KEKU59WPf/1

Comment: This is EXPLAIN problem. While commenting it everything works. [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wB7Ee9Rz8nLS3KEKU59WPf/2). Edit your question, add links to fiddles and point the problem to EXPLAIN statement.

Comment: It's not an Explain problem. If you run that update command without EXPLAIN, it still fails. Yes, I am adding the link in the question.

Comment: It doesn't work in version 8.0.12 (used by https://www.db-fiddle.com), but it does work in version 8.0.20 (used by https://dbfiddle.uk).

Answer (score 1):

Everything works OK while typing with accuracy.

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wB7Ee9Rz8nLS3KEKU59WPf/5)

Search for wrong char (maybe national?).

---

> You have changed the query to do set t1.xyz = t2.xyz, it causes a problem when it's t1.abc = t2.abc since abc is of type json => db-fiddle.com/f/wB7Ee9Rz8nLS3KEKU59WPf/6

This looks like join buffer oversize or something similar.

See [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wB7Ee9Rz8nLS3KEKU59WPf/7). Replacing `t1.field=t2.field` with `TRIM(t1.field)=TRIM(t2.field)` removes the error.

Testing on the values which have 512 chars length (using values like `REPEAT('a', 512)`) shows that the query is executed without error...

Comment: You have changed the query to do set t1.xyz = t2.xyz, it causes a problem when it's t1.abc = t2.abc since abc is of type json => https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wB7Ee9Rz8nLS3KEKU59WPf/6

Comment: Do you think, it's a mysql 5.7 bug or something, since it works on 8?

Comment: FYI, if I make one of the columns in the primary key as 508, it works without TRIM.

Comment: @Talha 508? strange... I would understand if it was 506... o! maybe this 4 bytes is datalengths bytes (2 values, 2 bytes per value)?

Comment: I didn't understand the question. I'm talking about making one of the columns in the primary key as varchar(508) keeping encoding of the table as latin1 only, without touching the data in the table/column.
Is there an explanation if it would have been 506?